# Increment in TicketNumber

Tags: vb.net, auto-increment

Im Having trouble with regards to the increment to output a custom ticket number in my project currently im trying this code but it always show this error message "**Additional information: Conversion from string to type 'Double' is not valid"**

```
Function AutoID()
    command.Connection = connection
    connection.Open()
    command.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM tnumber"
    If IsDBNull(command.ExecuteScalar) Then
        number = 1
        lblTN.Text = letters + number

    Else
        number = command.ExecuteScalar + 1
        lblTN.Text = letters + number

    End If
    command.Dispose()
    connection.Close()
    connection.Dispose()

    Return number
End Function

Private Sub btnRegular_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegular.Click

    If letters = "HMD" Then

        PictureBox1.Visible = False
        lblCounterName.Text = "COUNTER 1"
        lblTime.Text = Date.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy | hh:mm:ss tt")
        btnPriority.Visible = False
        btnRegular.Text = "PROCEED"
        AutoID()
    end if
```

Comment: Perhaps you can help us to help you by letting us know which line has the error?

Comment: ` If IsDBNull(command.ExecuteScalar) Then
            number = 1
            lblTN.Text = letters + number

        Else
            number = command.ExecuteScalar + 1
            lblTN.Text = letters + number

        End If` 

the error is referring to this one i declared letters as string and number as integer

Comment: What type is `number` and where is it declared? You should set `Option Strict On`...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are getting error due to the statement

`number = command.ExecuteScalar + 1`.

Here the `command.ExecuteScalar` is a string and so when you add 1 to it, it concatenates 1 to itself, and later when you try to store its value in `number`, then the error arises.

The error arises due to the fact that `command.ExecuteScalar` and `number` is an integer.

Before doing this operation you have to convert string to integer.

Replace that statement with this:

`number = Integer.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar) + 1`

Here we are converting string to integer and then adding 1 to it and later storing its value to number